# Why won't Python display this text correctly? (UTF-8 Decoding Issue)

Tags: python, html, utf-8, python-3.x

```
import urllib.request as u

zipcode = str(47401)
url = 'http://watchdog.net/us/?zip=' + zipcode
con = u.urlopen(url)

page = str(con.read())
value3 = int(page.find("<title>")) + 7
value4 = int(page.find("</title>")) - 15
district = str(page[value3:value4])
print(district)
newdistrict = district.replace("\xe2\x80\x99","'")
print(newdistrict)
```

For some reason, my code is pulling in the title in the following format: `IN-09: Indiana\xe2\x80\x99s 9th`. I know the `\xe` string of characters is unicode for the `'` symbol, but I can't figure out how to get python to replace that set of characters with the `'` symbol. I've tried decoding the string but it's already in unicode and the replace code above doesn't change anything. Any advice as to what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried using `unicode` literals?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, could you provide a bit more information?

Comment: It's not `'`, it's `’` (U+2019, RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK).

Comment: Seeing as you're using `urllib.request`, I presume you're using Python 3.

Comment: Yup, using Python 3. It's odd, even if I do a district.find("\xe2\x80\x99"), the value it's assigning is -1, implying that it isn't finding that string of characters within the district variable, even though it's printing it on the screen when the print function is called.

Comment: Precisely. It doesn't contain `'\xe1\x80\x99'`; it contains `'\\xe1\\x80\\x99'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `con.text()`, this returns a `bytes` object. Calling `str()` on it returns a string of the *representation* of it - thus, the escapes are used rather than the real characters, if you don't specify an encoding. (That means that your string ends up containing `\\xe2\\x80\\x99` as well as all sorts of other undesired things.) `bytes` is mostly like `str` in Python 2: it doesn't have any encoding information stored. `str` in Python 3 is like `unicode` in Python 2; it has the encoding. So, when turning a `bytes` object into a `str` object, you need to tell it what encoding it is actually in. In this case, that's `utf-8`.

Instead of calling `str()` on it, you would be better to use `bytes.decode`; it's the same thing, just neater.

```
>>> import urllib.request as u
>>> zipcode = 47401
>>> url = 'http://watchdog.net/us/?zip={}'.format(zipcode)
>>> con = u.urlopen(url)
>>> page = con.read().decode('utf-8')
>>> page[page.find("<title>") + 7:page.find("</title>") - 15]
'IN-09: Indiana’s 9th'
```

The only functional change that has been made here is the specification to decode the `bytes` object as `'utf-8'`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had initially tried to decode the file by using something like:
page = con.read()
newpage = page.decode('utf-8')
which had worked on previous assignments but was giving me a blank page here. Then I found that by removing the decode line I could get it to return the source code, so I just started working with that. Not sure what was going on, thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: Basically, it comes to the fact that `str(b'\xab')` produces `"b'\\xab'"` instead of `'\xab'` (it is equivalent to `repr(b'\xab') as there is no meaningful conversion without specifying the encoding).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
newdistrict = district.encode("**THE_INPUT_STRING_ENCODING**").replace("\\xe2\\x80\\x99","'")
```

i think that you are using utf-8 so it shoud look like this

```
newdistrict = district.encode("utf-8").replace("\\xe2\\x80\\x99","'")
```

but this isn't the correct why to work with unicode.
once your text is imported into the program you should work in unicode all over the place 
except maybe when you output as the output should consider the external destination

so a better why is to add  line at the top of your script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

read you input as utf-8

```
page = con.read().decode('utf-8')
```

and then  do 
    newdistrict = district.replace(**u"YOUR_UNICODE_STRING"**,"'")

for example

```
newdistrict = district.replace(u"דכעדחלגעדיל","'")
```

for more help read this

http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Your answer isn't correct as it's Python 3 he's dealing with.