# Finding regex, unicode patterns

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-2.7

I'm trying to scrape a website where unicode characters are present. I stated at the very begining `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` plus I used the `re.UNICODE` flag

```
pattern = re.compile('(?:{}|{})'.format(regex, regex1), re.UNICODE)
```

However when I print the output I still get those weird chars like `�`

How do I fix that? Thanks!

Comment: You might get the � glyph simply because your font doesn't support the respective Unicode character.

Comment: It does a hundred percent.

Comment: You have to decode the UTF-8 text from the website first. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293234/why-wont-python-display-this-text-correctly-utf-8-decoding-issue), for example.

Answer (score 4):

Just because a page it has non-latin character doesn't mean it's encoded with unicode (also, which unicode encoding? utf-8? utf-16?).

Additionally, [`re.UNICODE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) probably doesn't do what you think it does. From the docs:

> Make `\w, \W, \b, \B, \d, \D, \s` and `\S` dependent on the Unicode character properties database.

All this means is that these specific character classes are more broadly defined, it has no effect on the source text.

Moreover, the [coding definition](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is only specifying the encoding of *your source file*.

Finally, as noted in one of the comments, the � can be the result of using a character which is not supported by the current typeface. This, in turn, can be the result of assuming a certain encoding while the text is encoded in a different encoding.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still struggling. I'm certain it's `utf-8`

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an "answer", per-se.. but you could try using http://www.debuggex.com to debug your regexp a bit.

Comment: You should leave this as a comment instead of an answer then.

Comment: Not sure why (probably because my stackoverflow reputation isn't high enough?) but I don't seem to have the option to leave comments on anything except my own answer... that doesn't seem right though...