# Issue scraping a PDF with Python then encoding in utf-8

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I am scraping a number of pdfs from the web using Python so that I can convert them into text files for analysis in R.

I'm using pdfminer and then encoding them in utf-8, but the finished text file still contains a number of representations of byte objects (e.g. '\xe2\x80\x94') rather than the desired characters themselves.

My query is similar to this one [Why won't Python display this text correctly? (UTF-8 Decoding Issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293234/why-wont-python-display-this-text-correctly-utf-8-decoding-issue), the difference being that I have already encoded my byte object in utf-8 and am still having the same issue.

My code is as follows:

```
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from io import StringIO
from io import open
from urllib.request import urlopen

def readPDF(pdfile):
    rsrcmgr=PDFResourceManager()
    retstr=StringIO()
    laparams=LAParams()
    device=TextConverter(rsrcmgr,retstr,laparams=laparams)
    process_pdf(rsrcmgr,device,pdfFile)
    device.close()
    content=retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return content`

pdfFile=urlopen(webaddress)
outputString=readPDF(pdfFile)
proceedings=outputString.encode('utf-8')
proceedings=str(proceedings)
file=open(filename,"w")
file.write(proceedings)
file.close()
```

Apologies if this is rather simple. Am quite new to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following block of code is unnecessary and potentially erroneously encoding and decoding your data. See inline comments.

```
proceedings=outputString.encode('utf-8') # creates a UTF-8 byte object
proceedings=str(proceedings) # creates string representation <- the source of your issue
file=open(filename,"w") # encodes str to platform specific encoding.
```

**Edit**: Thanks to @MarkTolonen: `str()` returns '“informal” or nicely printable' str of the bytes (does not decoded by default like I thought). I.e. `proceedings == "b'stuff'"`.

The first step is to simply that block and remove ambiguity. Set the encoding when you `open()` the output file instead:

```
file=open(filename,"w", encoding="utf-8")
file.write(proceedings)
file.close()
```

**Tip**. Use the `with` statement to set a file context. This allows the file to close after the context finishes. Also, it's best practice to not use `file`, as it's also a type. Replace the above code with:

```
with open(filename, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as proceedings_file:
    proceedings_file.write(proceedings)
```

Comment: `file` is no longer a type in Python 3.

Comment: `str(proceedings)` actually returns the string representation of the bytes object created in the previous line, e.g., `"b'stuff'"`.

Comment: hi @MarkTolonen. Yeah, that's what I wrote - `str(proceedings)` creates a [Unicode] str [from bytes (by decoding)]. Right? Thanks for the tip on `file`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I thought `str()` decoded using implied default encoding. So my answer should resolve the OP's answer - albeit indirectly :$

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot!

Comment: Yes it works if I simply omit the two lines of code where I create a byte object and a utf-8 representation. Many thanks.