# Pandas Series.tolist Incorrectly Transcribing Empty Space?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame called `df`, with a column called `eligible?` which can contain either `"Yes"` or `"No"`.

So I want to select all names from rows where the `eligible?` column contains "Yes".  So I do this:

```
df[df["eligible?"].str.lower().str.startswith("y")]["name"]
```

I look at the `Series` output and it looks as expected.  One of the names is `"John "` (note the trailing space).

When I do:

```
df[df["eligible?"].str.lower().str.startswith("y")]["name"].tolist()
```

I get back a list, but now the row that had `"John "` has `"John\xe3\x80\x80"`.

Any idea what's going on here?

If it's helpful, I read my DataFrame in from a CSV that was utf-8 encoded.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Why won't Python display this text correctly? (UTF-8 Decoding Issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293234/why-wont-python-display-this-text-correctly-utf-8-decoding-issue)

Comment: @jpp Thanks for the help!  Took a look, so maybe (since I'm using Python 2), I shouldn't even be encoding as utf-8 when writing to CSV to begin with?

Comment: Possibly, I'm not really sure tbh, someone with more knowledge of these decoding issues may be able to answer comprehensively.