# How do I read the result of a python struct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, byte

Can somebody please tell me how do I read the result b'\x9a\x99\x99?' of

```py
import struct
data = struct.pack("@f", 1.2)
print(data)
```

What does `\x9a` represent? Or `\x99`? How do I translate this back to `1.2`?

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored in a binary format. To get the value back, use `struct.unpack`:

```
import struct
data = struct.pack("@f",1.2)
print(struct.unpack("@f",data))
```

Related: [Why won't Python display this text correctly? (UTF-8 Decoding Issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10293234/5987698)